# css not working for header nav bar links

Tags: html, css

I have the following page - and the header links, such as "Our Tours" and "Pick Up Points" are not linkable and I dont understand why. Can someone please help me understand why this wont work correctly.

**https://www.comparestonehengetours.com/tour/categories.php?path=Day+Tours**

Such as source text...

```
<li onclick="document.location='https://www.comparestonehengetours.com/pick_up.php'">
<a>Pick Up Points</a>
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you might be looking for `<a href="https://www.comparestonehengetours.com/pick_up.php">`

Comment: `<li>
<a href="https://www.comparestonehengetours.com/pick_up.php">Pick Up Points</a>
</li>`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (the approach you are taking is *awful* and you should be using regular links, but it does work when I test it)

Comment: Just because the page topic is Stonehenge-related, doesn’t mean you have to write “esoteric” HTML as well. Use a normal link instead of this JS nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image] 
The div with class `.site-content.large-centered` is over your menu.So in that page the click is on that div instead of the menu.When you inspect the page you can see that.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em).column.large-centered, .columns.large-centered {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: none;}
```

remove the float none     and you can click the menu.And also   remove the javascript for menu linking put  the links directly.thats good

Comment: which file is this related to for removing the float none? I cant seem to find it.

Comment: I have uploaded an image.please check.The content is over your menu.If you remove the float none from the class .column.large-centered you can click on the menu.Check your css file